# How to use Ubuntu to kill processes in Windows machine on my local network?!

Tags: remote-access

Having two computers (*1 Desktop Ubuntu, 1 Laptop Windows 7*). Is it possible to kill a process of a given running service on Windows 7 such as *Skype*, knowing that I have its local IP address along with its MAC address for the Windows 7?

Comment: It probably is, though you would have to have the login information as well as having something like SSH or VNC installed on the two systems in coordination with the IP.

Comment: Why did it get - vote ?

Comment: @ASCIIbetical Probably because of the lack of research. This is easily googleable.

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness Awesome Answer :D as in The Name reflects it ! :D Lol

Comment: I fail to see how this is an Ubuntu problem. You want processes on *windows* killed via *network*.

Comment: I think this question is fine, but you might get better answers on SuperUser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It probably is, though you would have to have the login information as well as having something like SSH or VNC installed on the two systems in coordination with the IP.

From the Ubuntu Community Documentation [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH)

> SSH ("Secure SHell") is a protocol for securely accessing one computer
>   from another.

The quickest way would be via SSH, as it is simply text, no GUI needed. You can do this via `ssh user@host`. However, if your username on Ubuntu is the same as your username on Windows, then you could simply run `ssh hostname`, it will automatically take your Ubuntu username and use it.

You would also need to install an SSH  server on your Windows PC, so you can log in. Read this page to help you set up OpenSSH (the same as on Ubuntu) on Windows 7.

From the ssh on Windows 7 page:

> A quick Google search reveleaed the existence of the [sshwindows](http://sshwindows.sourceforge.net/)
>   project which is a more lightweight solution than a full [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/)
>   installation.

From the page about SSH on Ubuntu:

> To use SSH, you will need to install an SSH client on the computer you
>   connect from, and an SSH server on the computer you connect to. The
>   most popular Linux SSH client and Linux SSH server are maintained by
>   the OpenSSH project.
>
> The OpenSSH client is included in Ubuntu by default. For information
>   on connecting to an SSH server, see Connecting to an OpenSSH Server.
>
> To install the OpenSSH server, install the following package:
>   openssh-server.

While I'm not sure, once you are logged in I think you should just be able to run the usual Windows commands and terminate the processes.

Comment: Best answer with details. Thank you very much RPi Awesomeness, I really get the idea.